# ColdFusion list value replacement

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a set of list values in ColdFusion variable, and I need to replace all the list values into desired text.

For Example:

```
<cfset headerColumnList = "FirstName,LastName,Email,FrequentGuestID,IP Address,Time Stamp Email Marketing">
<cfset a="test1">
<cfset b="test2">
<cfset c="test3">
<cfset d="test4">
<cfset e="test5">
<cfset f="test6">


<cfloop index = "ListElement" list= "#headerColumnList#" delimiters = ",">  
    <cfoutput>
    #replaceList("#ListElement#","FirstName,LastName,Email,FrequentGuestID,IP Address,Time Stamp Email Marketing","#a#,#b#,#c#,#d#,#e#,#f#",",")#
</cfoutput>
</cfloop>

Output:
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
Time Stamp test3 Marketing
```

In the above scenario. The value "Time Stamp Email Marketing" is supposed to be replaced with "test6" but I am getting in an alternative way where it is not replacing the phrase as a whole word. Can anyone tell me how do I replace the list phrases, any alternative for this?

Comment: Are you trying to maintain a list or do you want each new list element to return on a separate line?

Comment: in my scenario which i am working on those list values are DB driven values and it goes into the headers of the spreadsheet.I need to translate them into the desired language(ex.French,chinese.,etc.,,).So the code which i have mentioned above is just a example.If i could point out the above issue then i could sort it out.

Comment: Do they come as a list or are you building a list? Are they the column names out of a query or data from the query itself? You might be better off working with a different data structure if you can. Are a,b,c,d etc also pulled out of a database? Can you update your question with a fiddle or some example of what you are trying to do and how you are trying to do it? I think the example you gave may be a little bit over-simplified for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: In addition, replaceList() isn't working the way you think.  As Miguel-F pointed out, it searches for *partial* matches.  So replacing a common value like "Email" will always be problematic.  I suspect it's not the right function, but we really need to see a better example to advise on other options.

Answer (score 3):

Here you can use the ListQualify function to get exact result of an your scenario. So convert it in to qualify values and looping with that then you can replace it with your own list data. No need to change any order of a list values.

```
<cfset quoted = listQualify(headerColumnList,"''")>

<cfloop index = "ListElement" list= "#quoted#" delimiters = ",">  

    #replaceList(ListElement,quoted,"#a#,#b#,#c#,#d#,#e#,#f#")# 
    <br/>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: That does work.  Never knew quoting the list elements prevents that issue. Learn something new every day...

Comment: You can remove looping as `#replaceList(quoted,quoted,"#a#,#b#,#c#,#d#,#e#,#f#")#`

Answer (score 1):

The code is working as written. You are seeing this because your check for "Email" in the `replaceList()` function is firing before the check for "Time Stamp Email Marketing". Notice the word "Email" in that string.

I don't know what your actual use case is but you can change the order of your code for this specific example to make it work like you want.

```
<cfset headerColumnList = "FirstName,LastName,Email,FrequentGuestID,IP Address,Time Stamp Email Marketing">
<cfset a="test1">
<cfset b="test2">
<cfset c="test3">
<cfset d="test4">
<cfset e="test5">
<cfset f="test6">

<cfloop index = "ListElement" list= "#headerColumnList#" delimiters = ",">  
    <cfoutput>
    #replaceList("#ListElement#","FirstName,LastName,FrequentGuestID,IP Address,Time Stamp Email Marketing,Email","#a#,#b#,#d#,#e#,#f#,#c#",",")#
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

This gives the desired output. Notice how I reordered the conditions within the `replaceList()` function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But it works when we have less data.But in my case i have 24 list values which contains many "Email" phrase concatenated with the string.In that case something is messing up.It would be grateful if you could tell me some other alternative!

Comment: I have described the issue in the answer. When you replace "Email" with the earlier check then checking for "Time Stamp Email Marketing" no longer matches (because Email has already been changed). You need to rethink your logic. If you can, place the most specific strings first and then go to more generic strings. For example, check for "Time Stamp Email Marketing" first. Then check for "This string with email", then check for "string email" and finally check for just "email". I don't know if that will work for you without more details of the actual data but it should give you the logic to go.

Comment: @Miguel-F I think what he might be saying is that he doesn't necessarily know what can be in `headerColumnList`. I think 1) this is an XY Problem and 2) there needs to be a rethink of the way these translations are applied.

Comment: Yeah it's hard to tell without more detail and actual data examples.

Comment: @PradeepSubramani - Why do you need `replaceList()` at all? If you're just replacing one list of 7 headers with *another list* of 7, why not just concatenate the new values into a list `<cfset newHeaderColumnList = ""#a#,#b#,#c#,#d#,#e#,#f#">` and use `#newHeaderColumnList#` instead of `#headerColumnList#`?